# Ubuntu 18.10, как работает долгое нажатие command + L?

Tags: ubuntu, экран, lock, shortcuts

При быстром нажатии шортката для блокировки экрана (command + L) экран тухнет и без дополнительных нажатий куда-нибудь не просыпается (после чего сразу переходит к окну логина). При долгом нажатии на этот шорткат, экран тухнет, но затем просыпается и отображает экран блокировки, с часами и обоям. Как это работает и можно ли обменять значения для задержки нажатия, чтобы срабатывало наоборот?

Comment: а если сделать два коротких нажатия?

Comment: что такое command?

Comment: два коротких срабатывают как один, а command - это тот же Win